# Recurring Apache 2.0.52 error on CentOS 4 - 'could not create `rewrite_log_lock`'

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, web-server

I have been seeing a recurring issue on my web server:

```
[Sun May 16 03:10:19 2010] [crit] (28)No space left on device: mod_rewrite: could not create rewrite_log_lock
Configuration Failed
[Sun May 16 04:10:05 2010] [crit] (28)No space left on device: mod_rewrite: could not create rewrite_log_lock
Configuration Failed
[Sun May 16 05:10:04 2010] [crit] (28)No space left on device: mod_rewrite: could not create rewrite_log_lock
Configuration Failed
[Sun May 16 05:17:13 2010] [crit] (28)No space left on device: mod_rewrite: could not create rewrite_log_lock
Configuration Failed
```

So far, the only fix I have found to this when it happens is to reboot my server. This is non-ideal :-\

Restarting `httpd` does not clear the error. `df` indicates I have 20+ gigs free, and `top` and free both  report 800+ megs (or 1.2 gigs)

```
> df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs             40G   18G   23G  44% /

#

> free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       1474560     300832    1173728          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:     300832    1173728
```

Any ideas on why this would recur, and how to prevent/fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://devtime.blogspot.com/2008/02/apache-error-no-space-left-on-device.html

Apache Error: No space left on device

Apache doesn't start and the error log contains:

```
[emerg] (28)No space left on device: Couldn't create accept lock
```

or

```
[crit] (28)No space left on device: mod_rewrite: could not create rewrite_log_lock Configuration Failed
```

After checking your disk it shows that you have plenty of space. The problem is that apache didn't shut down properly, and it's left myriads of semaphore-arrays left, owned by 'apache' user.

Run:

```
ipcs -s | grep apache
```

Removing these semaphores immediately should solve the problem and allow apache to start.

```
ipcs -s | grep apache | perl -e 'while () { @a=split(/\s+/); print `ipcrm sem $a[1]`}'
```

where `apache` is the owner of the apache process, if that's not the name of the user on your server change it.

Comment: thanks. Could you copy/paste the scriptlet to your answer for posterity?

Comment: I needed to modify the scriptlet on that page to the following: `ipcs -s | grep apache | cut -b11-22 | xargs ipcrm -s`

Answer (score 1):

Way more simple with awk :

```
for id in $(ipcs -s | grep 'apache'| awk '{ print $2 }'); do ipcrm sem $id; done
```

Answer (score 0):

That xargs didn't seem to work for me, so in bash I did this instead:

for x in `ipcs -s | grep apache | cut -b11-22`; do ipcrm -s $x; done